# How to decipher capacitor markings

Tags: capacitor

yet another noob here. answer is probably obvious for most but not for me really. Just wondering how to interpret markings on these capacitors (red circles)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

ps. first lesson learnt :)

Comment: These ain't resistors, rather capacitors.

Comment: Those are capacitors, and I read 220n K which I am not familiar with so I don't know if they are 220n Farad or 220nx1000 is 220u Farad.

Comment: What makes you think those are resistors?

Comment: my bad, I thought its combination of both :/   just edited

Comment: @user3328469 caught the title for you...

Comment: I just noticed the line around the brown-black-brown silver **resistor**  which means it is 100 Ohm. +/- 10%

Comment: and the last photo, 10n Zm ?

Comment: Most likely 10 nano Farad.

Comment: Cylindrical and stripey usually means resistor.  A Chicklet with legs usually means a capacitor.  Googling on "resistor markings" and "capacitor markings" should get you lots of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a clue from the black silkscreen painted on the printed circuit board surface:

- **C** as in C20 is some kind of capacitor. Most of those you've circled are not polarized and could be mounted either way.
- **R** denotes a resistor - can be mounted either way.
- **T** denotes a transistor, additional silkscreen show "E"(emitter), "B"(base), "C"(collector)
- **D** denotes a diode. A silkscreen diode symbol shows which direction the cathode points.

The numbers following each letter allow multiple resistors to be uniquely identified...a schematic diagram would also show this letter followed by a number, and most often its value.

An example might be **C4 220n**...This is a capacitor, value 220 nanofarads. The silkscreen doesn't show the value, whereas the schematic diagram should.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two values that are printed on larger capacitors:

- The value or size of the capcacitor, listed with a number followed by farads with units, like uF nF pF or sometimes mF.  On smaller capacitors, the F is sometimes omitted.
- The voltage rating, a number followed V. The voltage rating should not be exceeded or damage may occur.
- Manufacturer codes (sometimes there, sometimes not) has codes for the manufacturer and can tell you what product line or even when it was manufactured.